# Python's “easy_install” on Windows - HtmlCSSInclude

Tags: python

I just installed Python 2.7 and easy_install-2.7.exe on my Windows 2003 server, then set  %PATH% to C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;. Then I tried to install a python package with easy_install, but easy_install failed. The failure follows:

```
C:\>easy_install HtmlCssInclude
Searching for HtmlCssInclude
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/HtmlCssInclude/
Best match: HtmlCssInclude 0.1.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/H/HtmlCssInclude/HtmlCssInclu
de-0.1.2.tar.gz#md5=0b4438bf62ae66842a514dcff67c0cd7
Processing HtmlCssInclude-0.1.2.tar.gz
Running HtmlCssInclude-0.1.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\admini
~1\locals~1\temp\1\easy_install-qpossf\HtmlCssInclude-0.1.2\egg-dist-tmp-haku7q
C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'auther'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: no files found matching 'testdata'
error: Setup script exited with error: can't copy 'sample.css': doesn't exist or
 not a regular file
```

Anybody please help me.

Comment: just to be sure - have you installed lxml?

Comment: yes. Installed the version lxml-2.2.8.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: Please help me to fix this

Comment: The reason why you are not able to install it - bcoz this package contains an error argument in setup.py that named 'auther' instead of 'author', so you can send them a message to fix this and try to setup after fix again.

Comment: I tried it. But there is no response yet. Is it possible to add this package from a local folder?

Comment: I was not able to do this locally. I have tried to fix the error and rerun setup locally but i am not very familiar with package itself. In any case this package is quite old and probably no one supporting it. I can suggest you to look for something newer, or trying to unpack and understand it's logic and copy the parts you need

Comment: I tried editing this package and it installed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are welcome, you did it without my help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried editing this package and it installed. 
Downloaded the package and edited HtmlCssinclude.py. In addition i found the reference to 'sample.css' and 'testdata' is not necessary for this package installation. So i also removed those reference. This help me to install package from local folder.